# Installing pecl/imagick giving me module api compile errors

Tags: php, pecl

I've installed php 5.4.0, and went to re-install Imagick, from Pecl. When doing so everything works well, but when apache starts the following error is logged and the extension is not loaded as it should be:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module\
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
```

For the life of me I can't understand where "20090626" is coming from. `phpize -v` shows:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

And the same is printed when the pecl installation process starts. How do I correct this?

Comment: Seems like you may have an old version of PHP linked somewhere. Did you install PHP 5.4 in a different place than your previous version? What does `php-config` say?

Comment: ok, php-config shows that it's somehow finding 5.3.8 somewhere - I would assume it's a default mac copy left somewhere. What's the best way to remove it?

Comment: For Mac? Unfortunately I'm not sure. It's just Linux, so check `which php` to find out where it has been installed. Is there `yum` on OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you when I compiled php from source. And had a previous php5-pear, php5-cli installed. I don't know why but I had to remove every single file still marked as "php5".

To find the files (should work on OSX too):

```
find / -name php5
```

Then just do `rm -r /paths/that/are/listed/php5`

When thats finished, just go into your bin folder of your new php installation and reinstall the mongo-driver with pecl. I had to do: `sudo ./pecl uninstall mongo` followed by `sudo ./pecl install mongo`

When the installation is finished, if you're using php-fpm dont forget do use `sudo service php-fpm restart`

Then it should work, check by typing (all this still in the php/bin folder):

```
sudo ./php -v
```

If you dont recieve any errors you should be good to go :)

//cubsink